# Google app script,gmail addon anchor with onclick method

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have create simple gmail addon using google script,in that i have struggle here,

how to use onclick methond in anchor when we click anchor tage we need perform some action,i have checked the document, i couldn't find any methods
The below code i have tried,

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<a href="" onclick="notificationCallback">TestLink</a>'))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Comment: No boss....i need more

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about the problem point of my answer? I would like to think of the modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `<a>` cannot be used for gmail add-on. A part of tags for decorating strings can be used. For example, there are `<b>` and `<u>`. So as a workaround, how about using this?

#### From :

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<a href="" onclick="notificationCallback">TestLink</a>'))
```

#### To :

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('TestLink').setOnClickAction(notificationCallback))
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

Since found this, added here.

basic HTML formatting: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply as follows

```
var exampleCard = CardService.newCardBuilder();
var section=CardService.newCardSection().setHeader("Google Services");
section.addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue()
                .setContent("<a href=https://www.google.com/>google</a>"));
exampleCard.addSection(section);
return [exampleCard.build()];
```